# Calling a web service when the ?wsdl option is turned off

Tags: service, web, wsdl, cxf

I have generated a WS client using CXF. My WS client expects the endpoint to have the ?wsdl option available. Now my WS provider has turned the ?wsdl option off for security reasons. My CXF client is no longer able to communicate with the endpoint. How do I connect to the endpoint without the ?wsdl option on. Is there some way I can have the wsdl locally and refer to it rather than expecting it to be available at the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

- If you are the author of the WS then deploy it on your local work station (even not working), then you should be able to get the generated wsdl. If you can get the wsdl and set the URL when calling the Service then, I don't see why it shouldn't work.
- If you have acces to server but not to the WS code; Another way should be to deploy a camel route on the same environnement as you deploy your web service. The idea is to hide the '?wsdl' part of the query.

  http://0.0.0.0:external port/external path to wsdl without any ?wsdl in it"/>
- If you don't have acces to the server nor the code of WS. Then your only solutions will be to ask the WS provider the wsdl or re-write it by using your knowledge about it; If it is for a commercial WS I would ask for the documentation. If it is open source I fallback on the first case.